# Error when starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just upgraded my ruby from 1.9.3  to 2.0.0 and then created a new rails project. After creating the project, I try to run `rails server` but I get the following error:

```
root@giri:~/sr# rails s

/home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: already initialized constant ActionController::Parameters::NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
/home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: previous definition of NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS was here
/home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: already initialized constant ActionController::Parameters::NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
/home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: previous definition of NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS was here
/home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- coffee-script (LoadError)
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `each'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block in require'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
    from /home/giri/sr/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`warning: already initialized constant`

This kind of error tends to happen when you have a different version in your bundle to your command line.

Try `bundle exec rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting cache. It is located under tmp folder